# ElasticSearch — boosting relevance based on position of query words in the searched string

Tags: elasticsearch

Need to find a way in ElasticSearch to boost the relevance of a document based on the position of the query words in the searched string.  for example, for query: "QUERY" the result:

```
'QUERY bla bla bla'
```

will be favored over:

```
'bla bla bla QUERY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the function score query, that might be useful for your problem: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/0-90-4-released/#function_score